# Tensorflow ImportError on OS X

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

TL;DR  getting `ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow`
  when trying to use TensorFlow on El Capitan.

Details: I followed the TensorFlow installation instructions for Mac OS X from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation).

> Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 2.7:
>
> ```
> $ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl
>
> $ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl
>
> $ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
> ```

These steps were successful.

So let's try it:

```
22:54:00/tensorflow $ipython
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: '/shared/.pythonstartup'

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-41389fad42b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     21 from __future__ import print_function
     22
---> 23 from tensorflow.python import *

/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     46 _default_dlopen_flags = sys.getdlopenflags()
     47 sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 48 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     49 sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags)
     50

ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Don't run `ipython` (or `python`) from the root of the TensorFlow git repository when you want to `import tensorflow`.

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963479/3574081). The easiest solution is to `cd` out of the current directory (e.g. `cd ~`) before running `ipython`. This will prevent Python from being confused by the `tensorflow` source subdirectory in the current path. The `./tensorflow` directory in the git repository doesn't contain all of the generated code (such as `pywrap_tensorflow`) that is needed to run TensorFlow, but does contain a file called `__init__.py`, and this confuses the Python interpreter.

Comment: ah you are correct. that is such a weird error I can not remember it.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks!