# Tensorflow No module named _pywrap

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am kinda new to tensorflow and only had some time to play with it on our univercitys computers that had it installed. Today was the big day when i finally had time to try it out at home but then i ran into some errors which i cant find any solutions for

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Might be some swedish in here but just ask and i will translate

Computer: i7 4770k 2xgtx 980 windows 10 python 3.5.3 tensorflow-gpu

Comment: How did you install tensorflow? It looks like there might be a path error or something. See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953210/error-running-basic-tensorflow-example which has a similar error

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I installed it using <code>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu</code>

Comment: Did try what was on your link but didnt seem to work

Comment: Did you look at the list of common installation problems here? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#common_installation_problems

Comment: Yes i did, and i even tried reinstalling visualc++ and still same problem. Looked after the dll file that some people were missing when they got this error and linked it in path but still same problem

Comment: Bumping, still have the same problem :(

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Can you try installing the CPU-only version and verifying that it works on your machine? 2. If the CPU-only version works, then there is a problem finding the CUDA or cuDNN DLLs on your machine... check that the directories containing them are in your `%PATH%` environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve been in the same situation for days and tried all of the above. What it finally solved it was to manually update my gpu card controller.

Go http://www.nvidia.es/Download/index.aspx?lang=es
make sure you choose the right model and download the driver. Install, reboot and you will be set to go.

Comment: thank you. Finally not bound to the slow cpu verision