# Tensorflow issue during installation windows 10 cpu only

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I am on a 64-bit Windows system with an AMD graphics card and I am having a persisting issue when trying to install the cpu version of tensorflow. I am using Python 3.5 and have gotten this message when trying to `import tensoflow as tf`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "C:\Users\leonardo.sanchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow No module named \_pywrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681969/tensorflow-no-module-named-pywrap)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this update https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

The similar problem is described on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5949)