# Tensorflow on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I've been able to work with TensorFlow on CPU, Now I need to run it on a GPU device with the following specs:

**CPU: Intel Xeon(E5-2670) and win7 64bit and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti**

I've installed python3.5 and Tensorflow for GPU just as described in TF homepage. when I run a test program here what I get when I try to `import Tensorflow` :

```
    (C:\Users\Engine>python
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):](url)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_h
elper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib
\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_h
elper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib
\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_h
elper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib
\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 22

2, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pack
ages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_h
elper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Engine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib
\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Does anyone has a hint how this can be solved ?

Comment: Do import from another folder outside of TF git folder. Did you see this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953210/error-running-basic-tensorflow-example

Comment: @hars thanks for replying, I'm starting TF from d: drive so I don't that the error has the same  reason !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @hars thanks for your comment. The second question solved the issue for some reason cuDNN5.1 is working fine, if you put as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import Tensorflow for GPU on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577923/cannot-import-tensorflow-for-gpu-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CUDNN might be one of the reasons. cuDNN v6.0 does not work for many people. Try with cuDNN v5.1.
2. Importing from inside GIT folder is also one of the reasons.

Good to know 1 worked for you.