# Error: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Today I installed TensorFlow using:

```
C:\>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-1.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: bleach==1.5.0 in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (
from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in c:\python35\lib\site-packag
es (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: html5lib==0.9999999 in c:\python35\lib\site-pack
ages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf>=3.2.0 in c:\python35\lib\site-packages
 (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: backports.weakref==1.0rc1 in c:\python35\lib\sit
e-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: markdown==2.2.0 in c:\python35\lib\site-packages
 (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (
from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (fr
om tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.26 in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (fr
om tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (fro
m protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
Successfully installed tensorflow-1.2.0
```

When I tried to import TensorFlow, it throws:

```
C:\>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_intern
al.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", l
ine 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_intern
al.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_intern
al.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <modu
le>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, i
n <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", l
ine 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_intern
al.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", l
ine 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_intern
al.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_intern
al.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

I'm using Python 3.5.2 64bit. I don't really know why the import process throws errors.

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error running basic tensorflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953210/error-running-basic-tensorflow-example)

Comment: thanks, solved, the solution is to install MSVCP140.dll from visual c++ 2015 redist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply download MSVCP140.dll, unzip it and then paste it in system32 folder..

Comment: link for the folder https://www.dll-files.com/msvcp140.dll.html

Answer (score 15):

My code worked perfectly after executing this line:

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 12):

First uninstall this

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Now for re installation Download this [tensorflow wheel](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/1.6.0/py36/CPU/sse2/tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl) file

Install this using(in same Directory)

```
pip install tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Had this problem for a week now. This is the only thing that worked. Thanks for sharing

Comment: "If your CPU didn't support AVX instructions, you will get ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Win 10) or ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795 (Win 7) when using tensorflow official release 1.6.0 and up (pip install tensorflow). You can use pip install [filename].whl which file download from sse2 folder instead of using official AVX binary." [Tensor Flow Wheels for Windows](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel)

Comment: `pip install tensorflow` is the first command a newbie like me tries when starting with Tensor Flow, not knowing that the version downloaded could not match the PC capabilities. Now I know I can download a specific version using "wheels".

Comment: The OP uses Python 3.5, downloading and installing a wheel compiled for Python 3.6 is not going to solve their problems.

Answer (score 4):

Similar problem occurred with me. I am using `Windows 8.1 (64 bit)` operating system and `Python 3.6.2 (64 bit)`.

I have solved the problem by installing `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (vc_redist.x64.exe)` from [vc_redist.x64.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Comment: Thank you. I have to use Windows 10 at work and that did the trick for me.

Comment: This didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have *Tensorflow Version 2* with the least dependencies, use this version:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0b1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to downgrade TensorFlow or use TensorFlow lattest version

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: if issue occur try below mentioned code:

pip install --user tensorflow==2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error on OSX Siera when i installed tensorflow through pip on python 3.6. It was fixed by using the [binary URL](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package) that identifies the TensorFlow Python package

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade tfBinaryURL   # Python 3.n
```

in my case [tfBinaryURL](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package) is as below:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. I had the same issue on OS X El Capitan and it was resolved thanks to your solution.

Comment: Thanks, my issue was resolved thanks to your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and I followed all of these advice here as well as many more from other sources in the internet and from my own head. None of them worked.

I had installed tf 1.2.0 and it had no problem importing it

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow==1.2.0
```

Further on, I found out that all the versions import well, up to 1.6.0., so I'll go about with 1.5.0.
Currently, the latest is 1.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

1) I did this : `pip uninstall tensorflow`
2) Downloaded the file from:  tensorflow wheel 
3) Then did this : `pip install tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

BUT it gave me this Error

> ERROR: tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported
>   wheel on this platform.

so I tried to install tensorflow as a dependency in my installed   [Anaconda Navigator](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)  
AND IT WORKED FOR ME!

Answer (score 2):

For mac users who us macOS X versions < 10.12.6 install tensorflow version 1.5:

`pip install tensorflow==1.5`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to install  [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Download [msvcp140.dll](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/8c211be1-c537-4402-82e7-a8fb5ee05e8a/B6C82087A2C443DB859FDBEAAE7F46244D06C3F2A7F71C35E50358066253DE52/VC_redist.x64.exe) and add to System32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to CUDA operation, since exactly this error is reported when CUDA is not working at all. Try from cmd e.g. c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\extras\demo_suite>oceanFFT.exe
If it fails, try to update driver (Device manager / Display adapters / NVIDIA...) of your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to [https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel][1]
2. based
   on python and cuda version  copy one of the path(I used
   compiler:VS2017 15.8 ,CUDA:NO ,SIMD:x86_64 and this worked for me)
3. paste it after https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/
4. download *.whl
5. open anaconda and change directory to location of *.whl
6. run this command: `pip install *.whl` (instead of * must be use name
   of .whl file)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I'm using a macbook unibody (2008) it works perfectly, and I can't update it any more, currently it's running MacOS X 10.11 (El Capitán). So, after being fighting for several hours trying to solve it, I've been able to solve it doing the next thing:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow

conda install tensorflow instead of "pip"
```