# i can't import tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have successfully installed TensorFlow using pip, but when attempting to import it, I encounter an error: `'ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'`. The error message also states that the native TensorFlow runtime failed to load. What can I do to resolve this issue?

[Error Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrvvz.png)

Comment: Install: Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 or 2019

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623184/error-failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime

Comment: It would have been nice if you have mentioned the OS, Python version, and TensorFlow version you are trying to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623184/error-failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python version Python 3.8.8 or above :

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

Activate your virtual enviroment and type the command in your console

```
pip install tensorflow
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Tensorflow package is of something around 200mb or above so be patient and let it to be install