# Tensorflow 1.14.0 error in importing the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
57
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import **version**

c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in 
27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
29     del swig_import_helper

c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
25             finally:

c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
344

ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py in 
26
27 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
29 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
30

c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*_.py in 
47 import numpy as np
48
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
50
51 # Protocol buffers

c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
75
76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "c:\users\sanjay\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you have run to get this error, but am assuming that it is an issue with the pip install. Again, not knowing what you have tried, the following are how I installed tensorflow to python3:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow    
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow
```

Or, alternatively:

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

Some sources that might help are:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install,

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip,

[error: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623184/error-failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime)