# TensorFlow import error at Windows 8

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-8, python-import

I just [installed TensorFlow via pip3](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) at Windows 8, using python 3.5.2 (which said *Successfully installed tensorflow-1.2.1*). However, when I want to load it, it shows me a long error-log saying that it didn't find many modules.

```
C:\Users\IQS-1>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\IQS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
>>>
>>>
>>> tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

I suspect that it does not find the correct directory to load the modules (similarly what has been [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953210/error-running-basic-tensorflow-example)), but I wasn't able to fix it yet. I'm very grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Didn't you get error messages when installing tensorflow with pip3 ? It looks like the installation process didn't complete normally.

Comment: @glenfant thanks for the answere. Tensorflow was successfully installed according to pip3 (i just reinstalled everything again, to be sure).

Comment: @NocoDean, this seems to be a tensorflow issue. Hint : try to reinstall in a new and fresh Python 3 virtualenv where tou are sure you do not need Administrator privileges. Then file an issue at tensorflow tracker.

Comment: @NicoDean Please let me know whether my answer is helpful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce exactly the same error as you did in **Windows 8.1** with **Python 3.5.2** and **TensorFlow 1.2.1 for CPU only**.

The root cause to this issue is because TensorFlow Windows installation requires the **`msvcp140.dll`**.

You can install this DLL by installing the latest [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587).

I am able to resolve the issue you're encountering after installed the above package which contains the DLL TensorFlow requires.

[image]

**Relevant reference:**

[On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso)

**Addendum:**

The same error is also reproducible on Windows 10 with the same Python and TensorFlow version as above.

In addition, user can also install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572) to resolve the error above

Comment: Great, i just installed that file you suggested and it worked immediatly. Thank you very much.