# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using windows 10, python3.8. When I want to import tensorflow module, this error happens and I really don't know what should I do, please help.

error:

```
import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. See
> https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and
> solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message
> when asking for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error running basic tensorflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953210/error-running-basic-tensorflow-example)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Masih Eshraghi, Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you let me the tensorflow version details and steps that you have followed? so that i can help you better. Thanks!