# Install SKFLOW to work with Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, tensorflow, skflow

Now that SKFLOW has been moved within TensorFlow I am not sure how to use it. I am running Anaconda on Ubuntu server and I installed Tensorflow as suggested in this question: [Tensorflow and Anaconda on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646541/tensorflow-and-anaconda-on-ubuntu)

My scripts are seeing Tensorflow but not SKFLOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have shared this in our Gitter channel but it might useful to repost it here.

You can use `pip` to install TensorFlow's ***nightly binaries*** as mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation) file if you don't want to wait until next official release.

Then at least for the date I posted this, you can import skflow directly from TensorFlow via `from tensorflow.contrib.skflow.python import skflow` and then everything else works the same as usual.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: Once [this PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/1712) is merged, you'll be able to import as done in examples folder in TensorFlow, e.g. `from tensorflow.contrib import skflow`.

Comment: After "pip install tf-nightly", both "from tensorflow.contrib.skflow.python import skflow" and "from tensorflow.contrib import skflow" still fail. Any suggestion? The PR you mentioned seemed to be merged to the master.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that skflow is in the latest, 0.7.1, tensorflow release. And therefore you won't find it if you have just conda installed tensorflow via the [post you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646541/tensorflow-and-anaconda-on-ubuntu).

For example, checking the [anaconda channel for tensorflow](https://anaconda.org/jjhelmus/tensorflow/files) it looks like 0.7.1 was uploaded on March 3rd while the first check-in of skflow in the tensorflow code base was on March 9th. I also don't see any notice of skflow in the recent release mentions of tensorflow.

That said, when it is released with skflow as part of it, I expect you'll be able to import it like this:

`import tensorflow.contrib.skflow`