# installing Tensorflow with Anaconda on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda

On my Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed tensorflow from source, as specified in the Tensorflow Installation instructions and it works well.

Then I install anaconda but it changes the $PATH environment variable, so I cannot import tensorflow.

Following the instruction in [Tensorflow and Anaconda on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646541/tensorflow-and-anaconda-on-ubuntu), I created an environment and installed tensorflow in it, as specified in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation. I use this command `sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL` to install tensorflow. But the tensorflow is not installed in this environment. It seems that it just updates the tensorflow I have installed previously. The terminal window is shown in the image:

I have solved this problem. Use `pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL` instead. Using sudo will sudo will install the package globally.

[image]

Comment: try: `conda install tensorflow -c conda-forge`

Comment: Actually, I want to install the GPU version of tensorflow and this command is not suitable for it.