# HOW TO: Import TensorFlow in Jupyter Notebook from Conda with GPU support?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter, nvidia, conda

I have installed tensorflow using the anaconda environment as mentioned in the [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation) and after doing my python installation path changed.

```
dennis@dennis-HP:~$ which python                                                                                                   
/home/dennis/anaconda2/bin/python
```

And Jupyter was installed. I assumed that if I was able to import and use tensorflow in the conda environment that I will be able to do the same in Jupyter. But that was not the case -

**Importing tensorflow in my system (without activating the environment)**

```
dennis@dennis-HP:~$ python                                                                                                         
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:21:30)                                                           
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2                                                                                   
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                             
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.                                                                                 
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org                                                              
>>> import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                        
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                              
ImportError: No module named tensorflow                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> exit()
```

**Importing tensorflow in conda environment**

```
dennis@dennis-HP:~$ source activate tensorflow                                                                                     
prepending /home/dennis/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/bin to PATH                                                                      
(tensorflow) dennis@dennis-HP:~$ python                                                                                            
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40)                                                         
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2                                                                                   
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                             
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.                                                                                 
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org                                                              
>>> import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                        
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally                              
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:2092] Unable to load cuDNN DSO                                                       
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally                               
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally                                
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

As the above import was successful I tried to do the same in jupyter *(launched jupyter within the environment)* but I got the following error on import -

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-41389fad42b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

My guess is that the notebook is not run within the environment of conda. So, can you tell me how do I force it to do the same?

Or you can just provide me with details about how to import tensorflow in jupyter

**EDIT #1:**

I have successfully installed tensorflow in anaconda installation using `conda install -c jjhelmus tensorflow=0.9.0` command. [Source: [conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus](http://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus)]

But this disables the GPU support, so a code like the one below returns an error

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  with tf.device("/gpu:0"): #GPUs are not enabled on the system so it throws an error
    matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
    matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
    product = tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2)
    result = sess.run([product])
    print result
```

**So, how do I enable GPU support? Is there an alternate solution to install tensorflow in conda with GPU support?**

**EDIT #2:**

It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646541/tensorflow-and-anaconda-on-ubuntu), that GPU support is possible only if the source is built for the target GPU. **If that is true, please provide details about how it can be done** so that I have a GPU enabled tensorflow installation.

Comment: what platform are you on? If you're on linux, google has now made a pre-built binary you can use very easily with anaconda. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you ever installed *jupyter* within the *tensorflow* environment?

Type `which jupyter` to find out. The result:

```
(tensorflow) [..]$ <anaconda_home>/envs/tensorflow/bin/jupyter # installed within the tensorflow environment.
(tensorflow) [..]$ <anaconda_home>/bin/jupyter                 # not installed.
```

If not installed, type `pip install jupyter` within the *tensorflow* environment. Then try to `import tensorflow` in notebook again.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Yes, I was able to re-install it within the same channels without issues. But I was not able to find out what exactly was wrong the first time.

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow 0.9 with GPU for Anaconda Python 2**

For **linux**, use Google's pre-built binary with Cuda 7.5 and CuDNN v4 (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation):

Pseudoscript: https://gist.github.com/nathanielatom/ccdf39d9f20dca4c9e418ea0e00ccd25

For **Mac**, install from source with Cuda 7.5 and CuDNN v5.1 RC (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#installation-for-mac-os-x)

Pseudoscript: https://gist.github.com/nathanielatom/8c51c91d4bde3e37db0db705e8822e70

Comment: As you mentioned, I have used the links that you have described to install tensorflow with GPU support. Turns out that the issue was on the setting of the path variable. I previously set export PATH="/home/dennis/anaconda2/bin:$PATH" and this caused the problem. It was fixed after setting the path as export PATH="$PATH:/home/dennis/anaconda2/bin"

Comment: Please add the detail about setting the PATH to anaconda so that I can accept your answer

Comment: The PATH with anaconda should already be setup from your anaconda install. Having PATH="/home/dennis/anaconda2/bin:$PATH" prepended means the anaconda python will definitely be the one executed. The fact that it works when you move it to the end implies you're actually executing a different python (maybe the system python?). Try `which python` or check if the anaconda version is printed out in the preamble when you start an interpreter session. Also, check `which pip` as it seems like you might have installed tensorflow into the system/other python.

Comment: If so (anaconda doesn't show up in `pip`s path), try uninstalling the system/other pip, ensure `which pip` gives you the anaconda version (`/home/dennis/anaconda2/bin/pip`) and reinstall the tensorflow pip package. After a successful anaconda install, tensorflow should live in `/home/dennis/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow`; so try to `ls` that. Also there are a bunch of useful example nets there.