# Ubuntu: No module named tensorflow in IPython but works in Python (Anaconda environment)

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, tensorflow, anaconda

When I try to import tensorflow in IPython in my Anaconda environment, I get a `No module named tensorflow` error. However, when I import it after running the `python` command in the terminal, there are no errors.

I've googled for solutions and so far I have tried the following:

- copied the site-packages inside `/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to `/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`
- installed ipython in the conda environment with `conda install ipython`

Anyone know what else I could try?

Comment: You didn't try `conda install` for tensorflow? Are you sure IPython is running python2?

Comment: Check `sys.executable` to see which environment you're running in, and `sys.path` to see where it looks for imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer: [Tensorflow and Anaconda on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646541/tensorflow-and-anaconda-on-ubuntu?rq=1)

I found a link where the tensorflow.whl files were converted to conda packages, so I went ahead and installed it using the command:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow
```

and it worked, since the $PATH points to anaconda packages, I can import it now!

[Source is here](https://anaconda.org/jjhelmus/tensorflow)